# What is the difference between IAM user and web application client user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, identity-management

I have developed a sprint boot shopping web application. Deployed in AWS cloud. the application has different types of users, -  Admin, Vendor and users across world who are using the application. I have to give Multifactor authorization and authentication for the users. Where to store, create roles and permissions and user account details ?
there will be millions of users of the application.
Is IAM used for that ? or it IAM users is for the developers, tester and team who develop the application and give access to different services of AWS.
Please help with application user and - developers/testers/project team users.

Answer (score 3):

Speaking at high level, IAM is not intended to manage authorization and authentication for users at application layer. **IAM is for specifying who or what can access AWS services and resources**.

Considering the requirements you mentioned, you might want to take a look for Amazon Cognito. **It supports [third-party authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication.html) such as Facebook, Google, etc. [making MFA necessary](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-mfa.html) for your user pool and [a secure identity store that scales to millions of users](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/details/)**.

For your references:

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/what-is-amazon-cognito.html
2. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/tag/amazon-cognito/